# Load arraylist into a TextBox

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

I have another question and I can't seem to find anything on Google.

**What this program does**
This program displays the information from an RSS feed.

**Question**
How can I load all the items from an Arraylist to a TextBox?

**Things I have tried**
This is what I have so far:

```
List<Array> list1 = new List<Array>();

foreach (var item in list1)
        {
            textBox1.AppendText(item.ToString());
        }
```

**Problem**
When I do this, the TextBox shows this:

> System.String[]System.String[]

Instead of:

> Recommended Build for CraftBukkit: 1.2.4-R1.0 (build 2126)
>       http://dl.bukkit.org/downloads/craftbukkit/view/00993_1.2.4-R1.0/

Does anybody have any idea how this array stuff work?
Do I need to loop through the array and search for specific indexes?

Sorry, but I'm still a little bit new to C#, and sorry for my English I'm Dutch :<.

Comment: Oh yea sorry, this is how I define the list:  List<Array> list1 = new List<Array>();

Comment: seems item type is string[], so what you can do is  `string.Join(',', item)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you ArrayList contains array of string instead of string. So try this :

```
foreach (var item in list1.OfType<string[]>().SelectMany(i => i))
{
    textBox1.AppendText(item);
}
```

Comment: for what .SelectMany(i => i) ?

Comment: @Manitra Andriamitondra This seems to work perfectly :)!  Thank you! EDIT: I can't accept the answer yet, need to wait another 7 minutes ):.

Comment: SelectMany() converts a `list of list` to a flat `list`

Comment: There must be something alike Concat or All for it. (I'm not really sure but I think so)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `item` is a string array, so try to implode it:

```
foreach (var item in list1)
{
    textBox1.AppendText(string.Join("", item));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is basically a list of array. That's why it is showing system.string[]

Change it to

```
foreach (var item in list1)
{
    textBox1.AppendText(string.Join("", item));
}
```

It will join your each string[] (i.e. item) in List<> and create it like

firstarrrayfirstitem, firstarrayseconditem

and textbox as

firstarrrayfirstitem, firstarrayseconditem, secondarrayfirstitem, secondarrayseconditem.... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

A better way could be to use a stringbuider for better performance and reduction in a propertychanged event called by the textbox;

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

foreach (var item in list1.OfType<string[]>().SelectMany(i => i))
{
    sb.Append(item);
}

textBox1.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way:

```
textBox1.Text = string.Join("", list1.OfType<string[]>().SelectMany(i => i));
```